# Deriving TDEE from calorie intake and weight changes over time

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, calories, weight-gain

I have historical data for my own calorie intake and weight over the past few years. I'd like to calculate my TDEE from this data. Can anyone point me towards an appropriate mathematical model? Googling around I've found some papers (like [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2764961)) that predict future weight gain as a function of an increase in calorie intake, but I am not sure that is quite what I want -- I plan to continue measuring my weight and calorie intakes going forward, so I'm not interested in trying to project a long way into the future.

I am aware of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/nSuns/comments/6lv33j/faq_about_tdee_30/) TDEE calculator that does something similar, but I'd like to get a better understanding of the math from first principles.

Answer (score -1):

You can't approximate TDEE, you can just throw random numbers. 
But you can actually calculate it with precision, Basal metabolic rate+calories burned through activity. 
You just need to register everything you do for a weak or even more, then get an average.

For example today I consumed 1677 kcals for BMR plus 273 kcals of running and roughly 70-73 kcals of weight training and 94 kcals of walking around.

Comment: I have estimated calories burned through my fitbit but studies have shown that it can be off by as much as 40%: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27015387/. I think it would be more accurate to calculate it based on my weight + calorie intake if I had a good way to e.g. filter out the noise of swings in water weight.